# Mathjax can't render some of LaTeX basic commands

Tags: macros, mathjax

Sorry this is probably a very silly question as I'm too new to LaTeX.

Mathjax has issues rendering basic LaTeX commands like /xspace and /ensuremath

There are some custom macros in my LaTeX files, and I define them in MathJax config as;

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    tex2jax: {
        inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
        displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
        processEscapes: false,
        element: "content",
        ignoreClass: "(tex2jax_ignore|mw-search-results|searchresults)", /* note: this is part of a regex, check the docs! */
        skipTags: ["script","noscript","style","textarea","code"] /* removed pre as wikimedia renders math in there */
    },
    TeX: {
        extensions: ["AMSmath.js"],
        Macros: {
            COM: ['{\\ensuremath{\\left[ {#1} , {#2}\\right]}\\xspace}', 2]
        }
    }
});
```

HTML Code:

```
A nonzero commutator between two operators $\hat {A}$ and $\hat {B}$, denoted $\COM {\hat {A}}{\hat {B}}=\hat {A}\hat {B}-\hat {B}\hat {A}$.
```

Output:

[image: screenshot]

I couldnt find how to define these, guessing it could be a package/extension to include in MathJax settings or something to do within original LaTeX files before conversion to HTML.

many thanks

Comment: MathJax is not TeX/LaTeX; if a macro is not supported by MathJax nothing can be done from the TeX side.

Comment: mathjax is off topic for this site (the mathjax help list is a better place) but in anycase it _only_ emulates math mode so there is no need for `\ensuremath` or `\xspace` you could just make the mathjax versions of the definition without that (or define them for mathjax to do nothing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thanks to @David Carlisle 's comment

```
Macros: {
   xspace: '',
   ensuremath: ''
}
```

did the trick.